# Has there been a surge in illegal immigration since implementing the DACA?

Tags: united-states, illegal-immigration

Back in 2010, Obama remarked that ignoring the laws and [suspending deportation of illegal immigrants](http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/remarks-president-comprehensive-immigration-reform?Source=GovD) might lead to a surge in illegal immigration.

> For example, there are those in the immigrants’ rights community who have argued passionately that we should simply provide those who are [here] illegally with legal status, or **at least ignore the laws on the books and put an end to deportation** until we have better laws.  And often this argument is framed in moral terms:  Why should we punish people who are just trying to earn a living?
>
> I recognize the sense of compassion that drives this argument, but I believe such an indiscriminate approach would be both unwise and unfair.  **It would suggest to those thinking about coming here illegally that there will be no repercussions for such a decision.  And this could lead to a surge in more illegal immigration**.  And it would also ignore the millions of people around the world who are waiting in line to come here legally.

Then in June 2012, Obama announced the [Deferred Action for Childhood Arrivals](http://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2012/06/15/president-obama-delivers-remarks-immigration) (DACA). The [DACA](http://www.whitehouse.gov/blog/2012/08/15/deferred-action-childhood-arrivals-who-can-be-considered) went into effect in August.

**Has there been a surge in illegal immigration since implementing the DACA?**

Comment: -1 for the continued use of out-of-context quotes that have no real bearing on the question you purport to be asking. This is an exact clone of your earlier question on this very same topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the President have the Constitutional authority to refuse to deport 3-5 million illegal immigrants?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6367/does-the-president-have-the-constitutional-authority-to-refuse-to-deport-3-5-mil)

Comment: @DA., you have a strange definition of "out-of-context." I don't understand why you think his quote has no bearing. A prominent politician made a claim about the effects of putting and end to deportation, a policy change prevented the deportation of 0.5 million . **How does that have no bearing on the question?** how this could be a duplicate of "can the president create executive orders," this question isn't a question of if something is legal, but what effects it caused. I am sure the DHS has numbers before and after the DACA went online.

Comment: I'm not cluttering comments anymore. Feel free to page me in chat. Or not. Whatever.

Comment: @user1873 I agree with DA, I don't see the relevance of the quote here. DACA didn't end deportation, so talking about the effects of ending deportation isn't really relevant.

However, I don't agree that this is a duplicate. It is a different question.

Comment: @Avi, You don't think so? "individuals whose cases are deferred **will not be removed from the United States for a two year period, subject to renewal**, and may also receive employment authorization." That might make another good question, if the administration renews the [0.5+ million](http://www.immigrationpolicy.org/special-reports/two-years-and-counting-assessing-growing-power-daca) every two years indefinitely, would he be failing to faithfully execute the law?

Comment: @user1873 I don't think that would be a good question, as no presidential administration can renew something for 2 years indefinitely, but only for 2 years 4 times. I still don't see the relevance. Deportation hasn't ended.

Comment: @Avi, "or at least ignore the laws on the books and put an end to deportation until we have better laws," deportation has ended for those 0.5 million until such a time that the USA has better laws (or Obama's executive order is removed by the next administration), if that ever occurs.

Comment: @user1873 the 2 things that background information in your question needs to do are:  1.  Help people in answering the question, 2.  Help Googlers to match this question to the information that they're searching for.   The quote helps neither of those things.  It's really just dead weight

Comment: @SamIam - they also need to establish notability - the reason why the question even needs to be asked. A quote from Rush Limbaugh would be dismissed as partisan BS by the same people downvoting now. A no-quote would be downvoted because "there's no reason to believe there's a surge". This goes back to my assertion that **in practice**, you can't win if your question's answer is not a positive for left wing here, in terms of voting. There will ALWAYS be someone willing to find some excuse for downvoting that sounds very high-handed.

Comment: @DA. - you're calling this "insincere" because it includes relevant facts that you personally would prefer to stay hidden. I don't think rational debate is possible here.

Comment: I'm tired. Page me in chat if you'd like to discuss further. I'm trying to avoid these silly debates in comments.

Comment: The puzzling thing is that reading the second link, a person can join the Armed Forces as an illegal immigrant.... background checks would seem in order.

Answer (score 5):

There [has been a surge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_American_immigration_crisis) since the implementation of DACA. In 2014, tens of thousands of immigrants, many of them children, entered America illegally. Most were seeking to [escape increasing drug violence](http://www.latimes.com/nation/la-na-ff-immigration-answers-20140621-story.html) in Central America. Many immigrants were also mislead by rumors of *permisos*, documents that would allow children entering the United States illegally to reside there permanently. However, no such documents exist.

Because this surge occurred largely in 2014, and the DACA only applies to children who had arrived here before June of 2012, the Deferred Action for Childhood Arrivals program does not apply to immigrants who entered during the surge.

Comment: Or to use the terminology: The push factors increased, the pull factors were not affected by the DACA. Also a fact I don't see mentioned that often: There isn't that much of a surge - the markup of immigrants have changed. THe numbers are really low compared to the 90ies http://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/ois_rfa_fr_2013.pdf

Comment: @user45891 Yeah, that would be a reasonable description. I don't like this question because it is trying to imply a casual connection between DACA And the immigrant surge where none exists.

Comment: @user45891 - the answer CLEALY states that the pull factors increased because of DACA - there are **rumours** of benefits to enter illegally which rumours are clearly based on DACA. The fact that those rumours are false/inaccurate **is irrelevant** to this Q&A, as the truthiness of them has zero impact on the decision making of people entering illegally believing them to be true.

Comment: @user45891 - also, comparing to 90s is 100% wrong (I'd say disingenuous) as the overall immigration plummeted post 2008 due to economics issues (i.e. job market in USA). You need to compare to post 2009 period

Comment: @DVK. Yep. [Joe Biden](http://whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2014/06/20/remarks-press-qa-vice-president-joe-biden-guatemala) had to correct misinformation coming from the coyotes, "Finally and critically, all of us in our meetings today agreed to work to counter and correct the misinformation smugglers are propagating about U.S. immigration policy, and discourage families from sending their children on this perilous journey."

Comment: @DVK I meant that the 2013 data is comparable to the low point of the 90ies (97) - and even the spike in 2010 is way lower than all of the early 90ies. And actually the drop after 08 still is higher than in 06. About the connection to DACA: http://www.vox.com/cards/child-migrant-crisis-unaccompanied-alien-children-rio-grande-valley-obama-immigration/children-coming-texas-illegally-crisis-obama-daca-migrant-deferred-action for me does not proof that DACA played any role in making up the permisos lie.

Comment: DACA only applies from 2012 now, but just wait for the next democratic president...